# SystemVerilog - how to use string as event or as time?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a transaction which contains:

```
string delay;
string delay_type;
```

If `delay_type == "time"`, the delay will have the following structure:
"`3ns`" (number and time unit).

If `delay_type == "event"`, the delay will have the following structure:
"`@(posedge clk)`" (@(posedge/negdge of signal)).

How can I use this in the bfm?

For example, in case of `delay_type == "time"`, I want to be able to do:
`#3ns` (where 3ns is the delay string).

And  in case of `delay_type == "event"`, I want to be able to wait for the event (for example for the posedge of some signal).

Answer (score 2):

You can't translate a string directly into code. Instead, you're going to have to parse your string. `$sscanf` will be your friend, for example something along the lines of:

```
begin : parse
  int n, time;
  string unit, edge, signal;
  if (transaction.delay_type == "time")
    begin
      n = $sscanf(transaction.delay, "%d%s", time, unit);
      assert (n == 2);
      if (unit == "ns")
        repeat(n) #1ns;
      else
      ...
    end
  else
    begin
      n = $sscanf(transaction.delay, "@(%s %s)", edge, signal);
      assert (n == 2);
      if (edge == "posedge")
        if (signal == "clk")
          @(posedge clk);
        else
          ...
      else
        if (signal == "clk")
          @(negedge clk);
        else
          ...
      ...
    end
end : parse
```

Not elegant, but hopefully, you get the idea.

Comment: there is no option to "paste" the signal to the posedge/negedge?

Comment: @sarar Not that I know of, unless you could do such a thing using the PLI/VPI.

Comment: by signal I mean to  vif.clk foe example (where vif is the virtual interface).

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Is there any option to pass a signal (of virttual interface) from component to componenet (for example from sequene/transaction to driver?

Comment: Not as a string, no. You could set up some arrangement with global variables (variables declared in a package), where one component chooses which local variable to assign to the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off trying to convert the text file of transactions you are reading directly to SystemVerilog. Or if you have a limited number of events, encoding them into sothing you can branch into a case statement might be feasible.